# php -v command doesn't show correct version on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, php7

When using `php -v` command, I got the following result.

```
PHP 7.2.1-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:55:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.1-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I'd like to use php7.0, so I tried `apt remove php7.2` then I got this result,

```
Package 'php7.2' is not installed, so not removed
```

So why does `php -v` showing I'm using php7.2?

Comment: Note that executing `php` on the command line *might* yield different results than the PHP version available on the web frontend in odd setups and circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you have `php-7.2` on your system, and would like to have `php-7.0` instead.

I assume that in order to install php 7.2 on Ubuntu 17.10 you followed a link similar to [this one](https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/), and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2
```

The `php7.2` you installed is part of a `ppa`

One way to remove `ppa` package is by using `ppa-purge` , e.g.:

Install `ppa-purge`

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Use `ppa-purge` in order to remove the package:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.2
```

After you'll remove `php-7.2` you can install `php-7.0`

---

> More info can be found [here](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/)

Comment: Yaron I would like to know why the command `apt remove php7.2` didn't turn up anything!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - take a look [here](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/)

Comment: @Yaron, I got this The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file. when using sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.2.

Comment: I don't mean why that method but why `apt remove` didn't find such a package and it's the same on my end!

Comment: @Zhenyu - did you install php in similar way to what explained in my answer?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - I didn't understand you comment. what do you mean by "it is the same on my end"? do you have php7-2 installed on your machine? did `apt remove php7.2` find/didn't find it?

Comment: @Yaron,  this is  actually weired. I never installed php7.2 my self.. I got php7.1 installed automatically from ubuntu upgrading to 17.10. And I didn't want php7.1 but only php7.0, so I removed php7.1 by using apt remove php7.1, and right after that, i didn php -v . and then it shows php7.2. this is so weird.

Comment: @Zhenyu - strange... :(

Comment: @Yaron, just for your info. I removed php7.2 by using command sudo apt-get purge php*, and then I installed php7.0

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply use following command ,

```
sudo apt purge php*
```

and hit enter. This command will remove all php installations, then after this you can install whatever version you wanted.